# Emacs silently appends -i to shell command

Tags: shell, emacs, eshell

And it breaks the shell I'm trying to run because it doesn't know the `-i` option. I've searched all variables that start with `shell-` but none of them has value of `-i` Setting `explicit-shell-file-name` changes the name, but the option is still appended.

Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a variable called `explicit-<your shell name>-args` (eg `explicit-bash-args`). Check whether it is defined and what it contains.

Comment: This is the correct answer.  Except, rather than *check what it contains*, my advice is to *explicitly set it to what you want it to be.  For example, on Windows, to use powershell as the interactive shell, you need to `(setq explicit-powershell.exe-args '("-Command" "-" ))`

Comment: @wvxvw: It is documented behaviour (see the last paragraph of `C-h f shell`) so you can rely on it.